# Reference to "this" is lost in function call after timeout in Angular2 using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular

I need a short delay before a server gets called. I tried using setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(this.callServer, 1000);
```

And in the function:

```
callServer(){
  this._item.someVar = "changed";
  this._service.deleteItem(this._item)
      .subscribe(response => this.onDeleted(response),
        error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

The function gets called but this causes an error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'someVar' of undefined*

And when i log "**this**" in the console it outputs **undefined**.

How can I access class methods and member variables after a delay? Is there a better method or some functionality I need to activate first?

Comment: This is answered in the TypeScript FAQ; see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does-this-get-orphaned-in-my-instance-methods

Comment: `setTimeout(this.callServer.bind(this), 1000);`

Comment: thanks @dfsq,  this worked, if you want to post the answer, i will accept it

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh should it not only be a duplicate if it has an answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh And can you please post a link to the original question. I can't find the question on your github link, and neither the solution that dsfq posted in the comments. The other stackoverflow question does not address setTimeout and uses a different solution

Comment: The fundamental problem is the same -- passing a naked `classRef.methodName` reference to something that takes a callback. If you think this isn't a duplicate, you haven't understood the other answer and should ask a new question about why you think these are different situations.

Comment: You could use arrow functions to avoid this behavior...